# Is normalization necessary for RandomForest?

Tags: python, data-science, normalization, preprocessor, feature-engineering

1) Is normalization necessary for Random Forests?

2) Should all the features be normalized or only numerical ones?

3) Does it matter whether I normalize before or after splitting into train and test data?

4) Do I need to pre-process features of the future object that will be classified as well? (after accepting the model, not during the testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **No**! Feature normalization isn't necessary for any tree-based classifier.

2) Generally speaking, normalization should be done on **all** features not just numerical ones.

3) In practice it doesn't make much difference. However, the correct practice is to identify the min and max values of each feature from the **training set** and then normalize the features of **both** sets according to those values.

4) Yes, afterwards **any** sample that needs to be classified should be processed with **exactly** the same way as you did during training.